# finding number of changes to make 2 strings anagram

Tags: javascript

I want to find the minimum number of characters of the first string that needs to be changed to enable me to make it an anagram of the second string. 
1st problem it always return -1

```
function anagram(s) {
    if (s % 2 == 0) {
        var len = s.legnth;
        var diff = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < len / 2; x++) {
            var y = s[x]++;
        }
        for (var x = len / 2; x < s.legnth; x++) {
            var z = s[x]++;
        }
        y = y.sort().splice(",").tostring();
        z = y.sort().splice(",").tostring();
        for (var x = 0; i < z.length; x++) {
            if (y[x] != z[x]) {
                diff.push(y[x]);
            }
        }
        return diff.length;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

function main() {
    var q = parseInt(readLine());
    for (var a0 = 0; a0 < q; a0++) {
        var s = readLine();
        var result = anagram(s);
        process.stdout.write("" + result + "\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: And what is the question and how is it related to C#?

Comment: Describe the question / problem. Also, show the expected input; actual output and desired output.

Comment: this isnt js...

Comment: @Jonas w i'm solving it on online editor the main function is from the editor and my function is anagram()

Comment: it always gives me -1 when i check is it even or not